# RewriteRule redirect URL with query string in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've no experience with regex, and the redirect rule I'm trying to put in my `.htaccess` file for a WordPress site is having no effect.

I want to redirect:

```
https://example.com/example/?person=name
```

to

```
https://example.com/example/people/name
```

From reading, I figure my rule ought to be:

```
RewriteRule  \?person=(.*) https://example.com/example/people/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From reading, I figure my rule ought to be:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule  \?person=(.*) https://example.com/example/people/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You can't match the query string part of the URL using the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the requested URL-path only. To match the query string you need to use a condition and check the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^person=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^example/$ /example/people/%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This needs to go *before* the existing WordPress directives.

This matches the URL-path exactly as stated in your question, ie. `/example/`.

`%1` (as opposed to `$1`) is a backreference to the last matched condition, ie. the value of the `person` URL parameter, that occurs as the first URL parameter.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the query string from the target URL. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then append an empty query string (ie. append a `?`) to the end of the *subsitution* string instead.

Comment: Thanks! Found I needed to add ? after %1 in order to remove the query string, but works perfectly.

Comment: @JohnG Yes, sorry I forgot that! If you are on Apache 2.4+ then you can use the `QSD` flag instead. I've updated my answer.